# the WCF service Does not respond on submit changes

Tags: wcf-data-services

When i try to update a property value using

```
var ccurrency =dbcontext.Currency.Single(q => q.Value=="1");
ccurrency.Name="ABCD";
dbcontext.savechanges();
```

Throw me error "Single is not supported".

The classes are residing under a wcf service using code first EF4.1.Please help me on this regrad

Answer (score 0):

WCF DS client doesn't support the Single LINQ method. You can use Where and First intead:
dbcontext.Currency.Where(q => q.Value == "1").First();
(The only difference is that the query won't fail if there's more than one entity fullfiling the condition in the Where clause).